# Apache Kafka(v2.4.0) - Spark (v2.4.4) streaming Integration in Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

So I have Apache Spark **2.4.4** and Kafka_2.12-**2.4.0** installed on different ubuntu machines. I want to fetch all data from say IOT devices, feed into kafka and then using spark-streaming, into spark.
I want to do all this in python.
According to this link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/streaming-kafka-integration.html
Since my Kafka version is more than 0.10, I can't use python as there is no example shown for python. Is this the case? Or is there any possible way to integrate using python only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is no example shown for python

That doesn't mean it isn't possble.

`spark.readStream().format("kafka").option(...)` still works in Python, and you can search elsewhere for plenty of examples of "Structured Streaming Python"

Comment: Does spark-streaming has similar functionality as Structured Streaming since as far as I know, Spark-Streaming is a separate API on top of Spark core engine but Structured streaming is a part of Spark-SQL API of spark.

Comment: It is binary compatible, as per the documentation

Comment: is structured streaming preferred over spark streaming api?

Comment: Yes. Kafka Spark Streaming is considered deprecated as of 2.3. See the page you linked to in the question